# Почему вы летает ошибка Uncaught TypeError: xxx is not a function

Tags: javascript

Я пытаюсь вызвать метод `tes2` из `test1` но всегда получаю ошибку `Uncaught TypeError: this.test2 is not a function at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous>`

```
class bookSelector {
    buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('sorting_point');

    test1() {
        for (const button of this.buttons) {
            button.addEventListener('click', function() {
                this.test2();
            });
        }
    }

    test2() {
        alert("qweqeqweqwq");
    }
}
```

Comment: потому-что это не ты вызываешь click, а событие, и `this` там будет привязан к кнопке, а не объекту. Попробуй стрелочную функцию вместо `function()` => `()=>`

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg это то, что нужно, спасибо!